# Python Files Parsing

Tags: python, file

Was wondering what the code for reading a File one string at a time

For instance if a file had:
'''
Hi My Name Is William
'''

Is there a way to read a each individual string inside the file like "Hi", "My"...

Not sure really. Relearning Python

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: readline function

Comment: Your code, show it to us.

Comment: open the file, call `.read()` to get the entire contents, then call `.split()` on those contents.

Comment: There are tons of resources which'll help you with this. I'd advise reading a basic string-handling tutorial in python. A file once read, is basically a string.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what a "word" is. The [regular expression library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) `\w` character class is pretty good, although it will match 0-9 and _ in additional to alphabetical characters. `\w+` matches a whole word and `.findall` keeps reapplying the search throughout the string.

```
re.findall(r"\w+", open("aaa.txt").read(), re.MULTILINE)
```